# Debugger issues with Visual Studio Emulator for Android and Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am attempting to deploy an Android app to the emulator, and am given the following error:

```
07-21 14:20:43.859 D/Mono    ( 1241): Image addref mscorlib[0xb87687e0] -> mscorlib.dll[0xb8767aa0]: 1
07-21 14:20:43.859 D/Mono    ( 1241): AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/TestApp.TestApp-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
07-21 14:20:43.859 D/Mono    ( 1241): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/0590d467/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/TestApp.TestApp-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
07-21 14:20:43.859 D/Mono    ( 1241): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
07-21 14:20:43.859 D/Mono    ( 1241): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/0590d467/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
07-21 14:20:43.875 D/Mono    ( 1241): Assembly mscorlib[0xb87687e0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
```

I am able to deploy to my device with the same API without issue

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue related to Hyper-V (the underlying virtualization system) and Intel Skylake processors. There is a published fix, which is outlined below:

1. Open Hyper-V Manager and select the VM for the emulator profile that
   your are using.
2. Select Delete Saved State if present (lower right).
3. Choose Settings...
4. Expand the processor node and choose Compatibility.
5. Enable Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor
   version.
6. Restart the service (under Actions) and try again.

These steps should resolve the issue.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_10